# Seeking solution for locating value between worksheets in unknown column

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I'm looking for an elegant solution to a formula for the following criteria:

*Location: Sheet2, ColumnB (row 2 onwards, the formula will be dragged down)*

- highlight/ select value in ColumnA, same row
- search for selected value in Sheet1, ColumnA
- return the value in Column(?), same row as the selected value was located in ColumnA, Sheet1
- If no value is found, return 0 (zero)
- (?) can be determined by matching the value in B$1 (Sheet2, fixed value), with a value somewhere in rowK in Sheet1

The following is a code that does the job, but I think it's quite inefficient, especially as this code is being used across thousands of cells. It is also difficult for my less-experienced collegaue to follow (this code is taken from cell B5 in Sheet2):

```
=IF(ISNA
    (INDEX
        ('Sheet1'!$A:$HZ,
        MATCH($A5),'Sheet1'!$A:$A,0),
        MATCH(B$1,'Sheet1'!$22:$22,0))
        )
    ,,
    (INDEX
        ('Sheet1'!$A:$HZ,
        MATCH($A5),'Sheet1'!$A:$A,0),
        MATCH(B$1,'Sheet1'!$22:$22,0))
        )
    )
```

As always, any help would be much appreciated.

Regards,
Chris

Comment: Honestly that is about as efficient as you can get in a single cell formula. You could do it via a macro... but it certainly won't be any easier for someone to figure out what happened. Alternatively you could solve across several columns so people would understand, but that obviously introduces more cells to the spreadsheet.

Comment: I figured this might be the case! Honestly I'd prefer just to macro it all, but it makes sense for at least one cell in Sheet2 et seq to have a readable formula in there. I've created a macro to replicate this vertically and horizontally in the worksheet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Decided to keep it as-is in formula as I don't want to lose visibility on the face of the worksheet. Thanks for all suggestions though - feel free to msg me if you have something better :D

Answer (score 1):

Try to use macros to solve this. If possible please upload the sample file somewhere with expected results. I can try and formulate a code for you.